# Как извлечь каждый нечетный элемент из списка?

Tags: c#

Интересно более ясное, краткое и компактное решение, чем

```
IEnumerator<T> GetEvens<T>(List<T> list)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i += 2)
    {
        yield return list[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Если число делится на два (остаток от деления равен нулю) значит, это четный элемент, иначе нечетный.

Comment: Наверняка можно компактней с помощью Linq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью LINQ:

```
var evens = list.Where((x, i) => (i % nStep) == 1);
```